# style applies only for ul li {} and not when I mention the class name like this: nav-links ul li {}

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I'm relatively new to front end dev and I can't understand why I get this styling:

[image: Image of styling problem]

with this code:

```
ul li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.nav-links li:hover{
    background-color: var(--goldnav);
    color: black!important;
}
```

And when I do the same thing this time adding the class name ".nav-links" to the ul li:

```
.nav-links ul li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.nav-links li:hover{
    background-color: var(--goldnav);
    color: black!important;
}
```

This happens:

[image: Image of problem]:

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like you have navlinks when you meant nav-links.

Comment: typo error, edited the code but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Please include your HTML as well.

Comment: alright, updated it :)

Comment: The ul element is your .nav-links class, so `.nav-links ul li` is not actually selecting anything.  The correct selector is `ul.nav-links li`, you could also omit the ul and just do `.nav-links li`.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I understand this now, thanks for making it clear for me, I also have another issue with styling the navbar, hope you can help me with that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector `.nav-links ul li` will match all `li` elements inside a `ul` element inside an element with class `nav-links`, for example:

```html
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To your case you can use `.nav-links li` (match `li` inside elements with class `nav-links`) or `ul.nav-links li` (match `li` elements inside `ul` with class `nav-links`).

Answer (score 1):

This selector:
`.nav-links ul li{}`

would be the selector for this HTML construct:

```
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

Means if you start your selection with the classname `nav-links` then the next selector must be a child if the node.